# Incorrect Subscription Plan Id in paypal integration using python

Tags: paypal-sandbox, flask-restful, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I am getting this error with my python integration:
Failed to create a billing agreement: {'name': 'TEMPLATE_ID_INVALID', 'debug_id': 'cf2bc405a0a3f', 'message': '', 'information_link': 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements#errors', 'details': [{'field': 'validation_error', 'issue': 'Incorrect Plan Id.'}]}

From the application I can see the plan id active with already a test subscription live which was done from the direct link

Here is the code

```
@app.route("/create_subscription", methods=["POST","GET"])
def create_subscription1():
    plan_id = "my_plan_id"  
    start_date = (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=2)).isoformat()

    # Create a billing agreement
    billing_agreement = paypalrestsdk.BillingAgreement({
        "name": "my_name",
        "description": "my subscription plan",
        "start_date": (datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'),
        "plan": {
            "id": plan_id,
        },
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal",
        },
    })
    
    # Create the billing agreement
    if billing_agreement.create():
        approval_url = billing_agreement.links[0].href
        print("Redirecting to PayPal for approval:", approval_url)
        return redirect(approval_url)
    else:
        print("Failed to create a billing agreement:", billing_agreement.error)
```